# How do I pass compile-time only global variables to my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I want to check if code running in development mode, and then, for instance pass redux devtools enchancer to redux store. And other similar cases. I know that I can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but its too verbose. I also can write it to variable once, in distinct module, and export it. But importing only that one variable and having module with only one variable seems irrational to me. The perfect solution I want to achieve is to have access to that variable globally, without importing or declaring it in code, and to it dynamically replaced at compilation time to just string i.e. `"development"` instead of `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Great example of what I want, is "pseudo-global" `__DEV__` variable in React code base. So how can I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you really think its too verbose, you could use the `window` object or `global` and assign the env value to it. `window.myVar = process.env.NODE_ENV`. But why do you think its too verbose?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't mean its really verbose, I mean I don't want to repeat myself, writing everywhere `process.env.NODE_ENV` instead of e.g. `IS_DEV`, and thats it. Write variable to window... I think its really monkey code. I would rather use webpack for that.

Comment: Well you have a way to get the environment via process.env. How many times are you trying to use that? and again thats not verbose, you should use the variable in a few startup scripts and thats it. Whats wrong with writing that out? IMO trying to alias the process.env variable is monkey code.

Comment: Wow, that was was a petty response, I didn't mark your question as confusing, but thanks for assuming I did. I do wish you the best in dealing with that, please remember there is a [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) that we are supposed to abide by, maybe take a few minutes and read that. Using an `environment` variable is a completely acceptable practice, make sure you're clear in your question about that.. as you dont mention wanting to use / define your own environment variable, but rather make a module that you can export it from in the code. Maybe it is confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Webpack DefinePlugin is what I need.

```js
// webpack.confg.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
//...

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  //...
  plugins: [
    //...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      IS_DEV: argv.mode !== 'production'
    })
  ]
})
```